# Importing questions from other forums into Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, questions

For SAP there is a forum called [SCN](http://scn.sap.com/). I do not like it: the design is bad, there is no `code formatting`, lot of URLs are out of date, etc.

Now one could think of copying and reformatting such questions and answers, and our great community would make even better edits and add better answers. All the advantages of Stack Overflow.

Now what would you think of that? Would it be good practice to do so for good and relevant questions (and answers), as long as it is legal from the copyright side?

If one sees a good question, (and the license allows it), one could copy it to here. Now I am asking if it is okay to do so.

Comment: Note that their content licenses may not be compatible with SO's.

Answer (score 15):

No, this would not be a good idea.

If you have a problem that's been asked somewhere else and not satisfactorily answered please do ask the same question, either in your own words or by copying (if allowed) and giving proper attribution.

However, this should be on a case-by-case basis and not by some wholesale scraping mechanism. There's a very good chance that questions asked elsewhere would not be a good fit for the Stack Overflow model without a lot of editorial work.

Comment: I am talking about good and relevant questions. It wold be [Q&A as SO wants it](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) I mean if I got a better answer for a question, what should I do to share? go to the concurence wher the community is not so active as here?

Comment: @inetphantom so there is a *question* there that you would like to move to SO so that you can answer it here?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I am asking about the general case.

Comment: _"I am talking about good and relevant questions"_ And how should those be identified by some automatic procedure, @inetphantom?

Comment: @Cerbrus who is talking about automatism?

Comment: So, you're suggesting a way to manually import those questions? I don't see how that's worth the effort.

Comment: If one sees a good question, (and the license allows it), that one could copy it to here. Now I am asking if it is ok to do so.

Comment: If the resulting question doesn't violate any rules, why not?

Answer (score 3):

Hardly a good idea. The asker being the person having the problem is essential to the SO model because:

- It is an indicator that the question is indeed still relevant
- Only the person actually having the problem can....

  - provide additional clarification that is so often essential
  - provide feedback on whether an answer helped them
  - request additional clarification from answers that is so often essential

Also, we really don't have a shortage of questions on SO. Quite the opposite.

That said, we can hardly prevent you from doing this if the license of the source permits it. There's just a very strong possibility that it's not really a productive idea.

Comment: are you aware of [the Q&A statement of SO](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)?

Comment: I am - but that article is about answering your own question, not copy & pasting other people's questions, no?