# Migrate our community to Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion

At Exalate, we have been using community.exalate.com for a while now, and we have over 2000 questions and slightly more answers.  Still - we think that these questions/answers would better be hosted on SO.

Would it be acceptable if we migrate all these Q&A's to SO?

Also note - Given that these questions are public, we are not looking to move these to SO for Teams.

Are there any guidelines that we have to follow?

Comment: Remember that your community needs to stick to SO rules. You won't be able to have different rules in your tag(s) when needed.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306737/importing-questions-from-other-forums-into-stack-overflow and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/341906/posting-a-question-that-is-coming-from-another-domain-specific-forum and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402427/does-stack-overflow-provide-any-means-for-an-existing-qa-forum-to-migrate-to-so

Comment: on a tangent: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269416/stack-overflow-seems-harsh-compared-to-programming-forums-ive-been-participatin and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283358/typescriptlang-org-redirecting-to-stack-overflow-as-forums

Comment: *"We"* sounds like you're talking about an entity, rather than yourself; are you asking on behalf of Exalate? The users of Exalate? Something else?

Comment: Thanks a lot with the pointers.

We would migrate the questions / answers, mapping tags to the known SO tags for these questions, answers and comments where the author has approved the copy.

The real constraint is that these questions need to adhere to SO policies. Is there a way to categorise these texts?

Comment: > "We" sounds like you're talking about an entity, rather than yourself; are you asking on behalf of Exalate? The users of Exalate? Something else? 

Indeed my question was confusing - I work at Exalate and we are looking at alternatives from what we have now (Confluence using the questions addon)

Comment: Please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, [edit] the question to provide the relevant context, and expand on the concerns that have been raised so far.

Comment: I adapted. 

I don't understand the downvote - was it because the question was not specific enough or is this not a question to ask here.

Comment: Votes on Meta mean the same as they do on Main, with the extension that they can also mean disagreement with the proposal, @FrancisMartens . If you *are* considering migrating to [so] then understanding how all of its parts work will also be important. For example, don't forget that asking on [so] is a *privilege* not a right; if some of your community members have a habit of asking low quality questions (initially) then they may well lose that privilege, and won't be able to ask questions when they need support.

Comment: @FrancisMartens it is mainly because it looks like you asked without prior research and in general the curators (that are often meta regulars as well) had to deal with content posted on SO by users because companies outsourced their support to the main site. That doesn't bode well so seeing another "migrate our support" gives them shivers and while still shivering triggers a downvote. If you had added you work for the company and shared some example of posts you plan to bring over the reception might have been less negative.

Comment: I see very little overlap between your software and programming. I seriously doubt any questions about your software would be within scope here at SO.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product)

Comment: Ask yourself this: do you really want to do this on a site where people will lose the privilege to ask questions within days because they will hit the ask question button instead of hitting the documentation? It has no chance to be anything than miserable for both your target audience and yourself. A support structure should be setup somewhere that does not have a laundry list of restrictions, rules and guidelines. Just don't.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> Would it be acceptable if we migrate all these Q&A's to SO?

I doubt it but at a minimum all these Q&A's need to be on-topic, so need to match the rules laid out in [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). They also need to be unique, so if we already have a duplicate we don't need a new one. I haven't looked at any of the posts but I doubt *all* Q&A's can find a place on SO. That is just due to how non-Q&A sites collect noise over-time that we try to eliminate here.

> Are there any guidelines that we have to follow?

Not only have you to follow all the rules and guidance laid out in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) but your community has to follow these rules as well going forward. For example: all their posts are subject to moderation: voting, editing, closing, deleting.

I would advice against bringing Q&A's over and instead start asking and answering on SO with new questions, patrol the tags, update the tag-wiki etc. Once more and more members of your community get comfortable with using SO and build some reputation then you can ask members to bring over high-quality Q&As that are missing from the body of knowledge SO wants and needs to be.

I highly recommend you read [Is it acceptable to use Stack Overflow as a Q&A for a specific product?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253849/is-it-acceptable-to-use-stack-overflow-as-a-qa-for-a-specific-product)  and [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) before you consider Stack Overflow as a support option.

Now I hate to say this but there also is a "paid" option called ["Collectives"](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives). That still requires the same care for Q/As but offers some additional features that allow you and your members to have a bit more leeway (*shakes fist at discussions and articles*) but I haven't looked into pricing or available plans. I assume there is a "Talk to Sales" button somewhere.

Do read the posts here on Meta about [collectives](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/collectives) to get an idea how the curators of the site feel about the feature.

Comment: Thanks - this is clear.  

In summary - If we would start to use SO as community, just promote the tag in our communication and answer here instead of our old community. Q&A of high quality can be moved over as long as there is no duplicate.

Comment: I will have a look at collectives also.  I was not aware about this 'feature'